# Sort Even and Odd numbers in array while maintaining order

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, partition

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segregate-even-and-odd-numbers/ I was looking up interview questions and came upon this interesting one. The algorithm seems simple enough but I was wondering if it was possible to maintain the order of the even and odd numbers while still maintaining the time complexity of O(n) without using any extra space.

For example

> input: {12, 34, 45, 9, 8, 90, 3}
>
> output: {12, 34, 8, 90, 45, 9, 3}

Edit: If it's not possible without extra space, can it work with the integers only rearranged in place? As in the swaps can only occur in the array

Comment: What do you mean with *"without using any extra space"*. Even the code you referred to uses extra space (`left` and `right`). Do you mean *"with using only O(1) space"*?

Comment: Without using any other arrays, as storing the even numbers into one array and odd in another then combining them causes the question to be very simple.

Comment: OK, that means using only constant space.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's unlikely possible as without extra space (dependent on `n`) you'll have to swap elements and thus disorder them (or you can shift chunks in the array, but that would likely require non-linear overall time; using other data structures like linked lists is not allowed in the problem, as far as I understand).

This problem can be treated as stable in-place non-comparison sort where all even elements are mapped to zero and all odd elements are mapped to one for comparison, and it seems there's no algorithm that matches these criteria (stable, time `O(n)`, extra memory `O(1)`) (see e.g. "Non-comparison sorts" table at  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms).

Comment: Hmm then would it be possible to swap the array in place using other arrays as buffer?

Comment: @user2435044: Yes, that becomes trivial: you just copy all the evens to the start of your main array and (in the same pass) all the odds to the start of your buffer array. Then you copy all the odds back to the main array, starting at the end of where you copied the evens. (Or does that not count as "swap[ping] the array in place"? I'm not sure exactly what you mean by that phrase, since the use of other arrays seems to imply that you're *not* swapping in-place.)

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant using another array to store the position of the evens/odds to retain the ordering. I was thinking of doing a variation of counting sort to achieve this but it gets a little messy when trying to retain the order

Comment: That should still be pretty straightforward: in a single pass you can populate the details of where the evens should end up, then in a separate pass you populate the details of where the odds should end up. Then you swap them into place, making sure to update the positions-array to "clear out" entries that have already been moved to the right place (e.g. by setting those to `-1`).

Comment: Won't the swaps end up changing the time complexity enough it won't be O(n)?

Comment: @user2435044: No, not at all, you'll need at most *n*-1 swaps. (Also, FYI, you should preface your comments with `@ruakh ` if you want me to see them. It's only by chance that I saw this one.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes It's possible. The Idea is to count total even numbers, then move odd numbers one by one to correct position.

```
    public void segregateEvenOddWithOrder(int[] arr) {
    int countEven = 0;
    int length = arr.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (arr[i]%2 == 0){
            countEven++;
        }
    }
    int i = 0;
    int j = i+1;
    while (i != countEven){
        if (arr[i]%2 == 0){
            i++;
            j = i + 1;
        }else if (arr[i]%2 == 1 && j < length){
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

---

public static void segregateEvenOdd_Sorted_Optimized(int[] arr, int n) {

```
    List<Integer> evenNums = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> oddNums = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
            evenNums.add(arr[i]);
        }
        if (arr[i] % 2 == 1) {
            oddNums.add(arr[i]);
        }

    }

    Collections.sort(evenNums);
    Collections.sort(oddNums);

    for (int i = 0; i < evenNums.size() + oddNums.size(); i++) {
        if (i < evenNums.size()) {
            arr[i] = evenNums.get(i);
        } else {
            arr[i] = oddNums.get(i - evenNums.size());
        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
    }

}
```

---